# What is the difference between a "Database Project" and a "Server Project" in Visual Studio Database Edition?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

When creating a new database project with Visual Studio 2008 Team Suite, Database Edition, you can choose to create either a Database Project or a Server Project.

What is the difference between the two?

The resulting projects seem to be pretty much identical. The server project still seems to target a single database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Database Project is meant to manage changes to user database, while a Server Project is used to manage server settings and objects and changes to master database.